# How to play mp4 video in server using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, axios, mp4

I want to play an mp4 video from another site on my site, but I have to send special header referer information when requesting this mp4 video. I have done a lot of experiments and I am leaving a few examples below. Responsetype streaming works fine but it looks like live streaming. So I can't rewind the video back and forth, it freezes when more than one person tries to watch it. Responsetype arraybuffer works very slowly. It takes a lot of time until the video opens. It can freeze when it opens.
How should I proceed? Can you help me with this?

```
 axios.get('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4', {
        headers: {
            referer: 'https://example.com/',

        },
        responseType: 'stream',
        timeout: 5000
    }).then(async (response) => {

        response.data.pipe(res)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('HATA');
        console.log(err.message);
    });
```

```
   try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4', {
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
          headers: {
            'referer': 'https://example.com/',
          },
        });
    
        const videoBuffer = Buffer.from(response.data);
    
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="video.mp4"');
        res.setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
       
        res.send(videoBuffer);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching remote video:', error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      }
```